# How to pass argument to url dispatcher from url template tag

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, jinja2

Consider the following url pattern:

```
url(r'^view/(?P<id>\d+/$)', login_required(views.ViewUser.as_view()), name='user_view')
```

Now, in a template I want to use the `url` template tag to obtain the reversed path to a particular user. I was trying to accomplish this by doing the following:

```
<a href="{% url 'user_view' id=assign_status.target.id %}"></a>
```

However, this is throwing the following error:

```
Reverse for 'user_view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'id': 2}' not found.
```

So, obviously the argument is getting put into a kwargs dictionary successfully, but evidently that can't be matched by the urlpattern. So, how do I fix this elegantly?

Comment: Try `r'^view/(?P<id>\d+)/$'`

Comment: ?? That's what I'm using.

Comment: Not really take a better look..

Comment: Thanks. I'm an idiot, apparently. If you post as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: glad to help mate, keep coding.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have small mistake in regex string:

```
r'^view/(?P<id>\d+)/$'
```